# How to search SSN from log files and XML with following characters

Tags: regex, xml, parsing, logging

I am not sure this is possible.  Possibly with a forward looking statement?  I am using a publish script conditional statement to match against Logs and SQL Server DB(XML row) for plain text SSN's.  I need to be able to match a SSN with any (possible) following characters that are not numbers using REGEX but exclude the entire match if it has more than 9 numbers with or without dashes.

So, in my code I have something like:
    If line.text matches [REGEX PATTERN] 
    Send to report table view...

So here are some examples:

```
((.*)?\d{3}(-)?\d{2}(-)?\d{4}((?!\d).*)?)
```

^This one matches 9 or more digits.

```
(\d{3}(-)?\d{2}(-)?\d{4}\D*)
```

^This one still matches on the first 9 digits

```
###-##-####   <- 9 digits should match
###-##-#####  <- 10 digits should not match
#########     <- should match
##########    <- 10 digits should not match
=#########a   <- 9 digits should match
=###-##-####a <- 9 digits should match
```

I've tried a lot of variant examples but can't quite get it.

Any help would be appreciated...and applauded.

Comment: Maybe `(?:^|\D)(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}(?:\D|$))`? Depending on where you use this the `\d` might need to become `[0-9]` and `\D` to `[^0-9]`

Comment: It is not clear: are you trying to match the 9 digits with no digits in front and after? Try `(?<!\d)\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4}(?!\d)`. Or use `^(?!.*\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{5}).*` to match a line that does not contain 10 digits. Please provide some real life data and expected behavior.

Comment: Chris85, that did it!  Thank you so much!  I worked for 6 hours on this one before posting.  Awesome, Awesome!  I'm so grateful!

Comment: Wiktor Stribiżew: I was trying to allow no digits on the the trailing end.  It is pretty much always found with an = in the front and then the numbers.  I have a long formId that was giving me a lot of false positives.  So, I was trying to eliminate those false positives from my data view.  Thanks for your answer.  My script didn't interpret the < symbol correctly for the first one and the second one didn't catch XXX-XX-XXXXX <-10 digits unfortunately.  However, chris85 had posted a working solution.  Thank you for reading and posting Wiktor.